# ElementService get entries by field

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, controller

I'm trying to get all elements whose custom field satisfies a specific value. I've got the ElementCriteriaModel but I'm unsure how to set the field and value I'm looking for, from the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/ElementCriteriaModel)

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
```

Any ideas? If I'm not using the correct service, then which is the recommended one?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Field in question is a datetime field by the name `startTime`. I'm searching for all entries whose date-part matches a given date

Comment: What's the name of the custom field (and what type is it) and what value are you searching for?

Comment: Will update with the additional information

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, only just had a chance to actually try it. It seems to work, thank you :)